# Shutting down a computer remotely

Tags: ssh, shutdown, remote

What ways are there to shut down a computer remotely?  My desktop is running Ubuntu 11.04 desktop edition and when I try to shut it down remotely using ssh, it doesn't actually work.  I used the command `sudo shutdown now`.  Afterwards, it said that the system is going down for maintenance NOW or whatever.  However, when I got home, I came to discover that the computer was still on stuck on the Plymouth shut-down screen.

I would like to know some other ways to shut down remotely and it would also be nice to know why `sudo shutdown now` doesn't actually work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Shutdown doesn't turn off the computer unless you use the `-P` option:

```
sudo shutdown -P now
```

Alternatively you can use `sudo poweroff` which does the same thing.

Comment: ...or use `sudo halt`.